# Shyam Pillai's Powerpoint Toolbox

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, export, slideshow

I am a paying user of Shyam Pillai's Powerpoint Toolbox (http://skp.mvps.org/toolbox/index.html).

Has anyone else noticed that recent Powerpoint updates seem to have made it impossible to use Toolbox, and has anyone found a solution?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a [Basic Customer Support question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company). Please see the meta post linked above for details on how to proceed if you can edit the post and, if put on Hold, have the Hold reviewed. You can also contact the developer for assistance with their product.

Comment: Contact Shyam.  You'll find his email address at the bottom of his new home page:  http://www.skphub.com/  You'll want to provide more info about which OS and Office version you have and what "impossible to use Toolbox" means exactly.

Comment: I've heard from him. Claims it's because I'm using 64bit, and his toolbox "was never supported on 64-bit version of PowerPoint", something not mentioned on his product page. I've been using 64bit for a few years, though, with no problem. Unconvinced, and unhappy.